# Adjectives as adverb

Tags: adverbs

Let’s say that someone owe $100 to someone but he paid $90. I mean he paid $10 less than his debt. In this case can we say

> “he paid 10 dollar missing“?

If that's correct, I wonder how the adjective “missing“ was used as an adverb. If it is not correct what is the way to say this sentences?

Comment: No, “he paid 10 dollar missing“ is not correct. Instead you might say something like "He paid 10 dollars too little." You may be interested in our companion site, [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No, that is not correct either: you need an adjective there to modify "10 dollars", not an adverb to modify "paid".

Comment: I would say "He paid $10 short / too little". I'd say that "too little" is an NP in a fused modifier-head construction.

Comment: If the debt is paid in cash, the creditor may say, “You're missing $10” or “This is missing $10” or “There's $10 missing”.

Answer (score -1):

You would use the word "short."

For example, you might say

> He was $10 short.

Often, but not always, it's paired with the term ["come up,"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20up%20short) as in

> He came up $10 short.

In America, there's an idiom to say someone came up ["a day late and a dollar short"](https://grammarist.com/idiom/a-day-late-and-a-dollar-short/), basically meaning that it's too little too late.